# Archive the modified version of file

Tags: bash, zip, sh

I need to change lines in the file and archive an already modified version of the file, *without saving it*, something like that:

`sed 's/foo/bar/g' ./file.txt | zip "a.zip" file.txt`

but still get `file.txt` with `foo` in the archive. Is there any way to do this trick? Or does it look like you need to archive stdout somehow?

Comment: I mean without saving a new version of the file:

`sed 's/foo/bar/g' ./file.txt > ./file2.txt | zip "a.zip" file2.txt`

i.e. without file2.txt.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

```
$ cat file.txt
a b c foo d e f

$ sed 's/foo/bar/g' file.txt | zip a.zip -     # zip reads data from stdin; saved in archive with filename of '-'
$ 7z -- rn a.zip - file.txt                    # rename file (in archive) from '-' to 'file.txt'

$ unzip -c a.zip
Archive:  a.zip
 extracting: file.txt                          # file renamed
a b c bar d e f                                # sed results
```

---

**UPDATE:**

- while `zip` can read the `sed` output stream from `stdin`, we end up with a filename of `-` in the archive
- in comments OP stated the desire to change this filename *in* the archive
- a google/web search brings up several references to `zipnote` and while I've got this on my system it's an old version (3.0) which has problems with the whole 'rename the file in the archive' thang
- more googling brought up some hits on `7z` (aka `p7zip`) as a possibility
- let's see if we can get `7z` to rename the file within the archive ...

Setup:

```
$ cat file.txt
a b c foo d e f

$ sed 's/foo/bar/g' file.txt
a b c bar d e f

$ sed 's/foo/bar/g' file.txt | zip a.zip -
  adding: - (stored 0%)

$ unzip -c a.zip
Archive:  a.zip
 extracting: -
a b c bar d e f                                # confirmation the sed output stored in the archive

$ unzip -l a.zip
Archive:  a.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       16  03-11-2022 16:06   -                # OP wants to change '-' to 'file.txt'
---------                     -------
       16                     1 file
```

First (naive) attempt using the `7z/rn` command:

```
$ 7z rn a.zip - file.txt
Command Line Error:
Unknown switch:
-
```

Does `--` work here?

```
$ 7z -- rn a.zip - file.txt
... snip ...
Updating archive: a.zip
... snip ...
Everything is Ok
```

Moment of truth:

```
$ unzip -l a.zip
Archive:  a.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       16  03-11-2022 16:06   file.txt         # file renamed in the archive
---------                     -------
       16                     1 file
```

And the contents of this zipped `file.txt`?

```
$ unzip -c a.zip
Archive:  a.zip
 extracting: file.txt                          # file renamed
a b c bar d e f                                # sed results
```

Comment: I was thinking of the `zip "a.zip" -` option, but I need the name of the file in the archive to be the same as the original file, "file.txt". "testfile" in your case.

Comment: @KarlsD fixed; was able to get `7z` to do the job